# « Quand » est pareil qu’ « Une fois que »?

Tags: grammaire, sens

« **Quand le gâteau sera cuit**, tu le sortiras »,
ça veut dire :

1. au moment où (as/when) le gâteau cuit

ou

2. une fois que (once) le gâteau cuira ?

Je ne pense pas que ça soit 1. car le temps n’est pas le même.

Comment: "Quand le gateau sera cuit, tu le sortiras" = "Une fois que le gateau sera cuit, tu le sortiras".

Answer (score 3):

Both suggestions are wrong.

1 means "While the cake is being cooked" (While the cake cooks)

2 means "Once the cake starts being cooked", which is not very different.

The actual meaning would be something like:

When the cake is cooked (i.e. once the cooking is completed).